# How to Stabliize Video when foreground and background are similar?

Tags: video, mp4, stabilisation

I have a [video of a lizard](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s3Bxp4Cowye8tbUilkhMpcVhgQfAlEjj/view?usp=sharing). The lizard matches its environment very well making it difficult for predators and algorithms to distinguish it from the background. I've tried using 3 different online video stabilizers and none of them work. I have no access to any commercial video processing software. I do have MacOs (Sierra) and Linux (Ubuntu). What can you suggest?